# Conjoint analysis in R

Tags: r, conjoint-analysis

I am doing a conjoint analysis with stated choice probabilities. I have collected data on smartwatches preferences but asked the respondents not for a single choice but to allocate preferences.

For example, when presented with 3 smartwatches and a no-choice option put a 20%, 30%, 50%, 0%, respectively for each option displayed.

Do I have to use the standard `conjoint`-package or the `mlogit`-package or maybe something else?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this blog post about choice shares... 
http://joelcadwell.blogspot.ca/2013/02/when-discrete-choice-becomes-rating.html

Answer (score 1):

One strategy would be to break each task into a series of head-to-head comparisons.  Create a dataset with one row for each comparison in each task (i.e. watch A vs. watch B in task t) with the difference in each attribute level and the difference in the stated percentages (likelihood of purchase?).  Then regress the differences in purchase % against the differences in attribute levels.  This would indicate how a 1-unit change in each attribute affects the likelihood of purchase.  As a first approximation this could be accomplished with simple linear regression but more advanced models could account for the constrained nature of the dependent variable.